# Laravel Middleware class call catch

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Hi i am new to middleware and wondered if it was possible to catch a php class, grab its parameters and do something with them.

Currently I am executing a call to the DB for every setting. With:
`{{Setting::show('default_key_words')}}` which just grabs a setting for the DB. What I want the middleware to go is grab Setting call, and the parameters and get them all at once rather than one at a time. Is middleware the right approach for this or should I just add a default call to get all settings records to the template in the controller then pass down respectively?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to access a database from the blade template (in your case) is to use the concept of **Service Injection** https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#service-injection you can create a service class in the App folder and retrieve any data you want.